# Substitute a block in an HTML Snippet using python regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Given the generic HTML snippet in text, is there any way to substitute block 1 by block 2 :

1. `<br /> Text2 <br />`
2. `<p> Text2 </p>`

So far this is as far as I could get using python and regex.

```
text =  '<p>Text1</p> <br/ >Text2 <br /> <p> </p> <br/>'
pattern = "<br />(?!<p>|</p>)<br />"
matches = [ match for match in re.finditer(pattern, text) ]
#matches = [ '<p>Text1</p> <br/ >Text2 <br /> <p> </p> <br/>' ]
```

It matches the whole text but I'm interested only in substituting in one go(one line). Is that a good approach, or perhaps you'd rather prefer capture what's inside, that is, "Text2" and insert inside of a `<p> </p>` block within the desired final_text?.

```
final_text = '<p>Text1</p> <p>Text2 </p> <p> </p> <br/>'
```

Comment: Regex not match noting.  Try `find (?s)<br\s*/>(.*?)<br\s*/>  replace <p>\1</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example is to give you an idea that you can implement by yourself.

```
from simplified_scrapy.core.regex_helper import replaceReg,regSearch
html = '''
<p>Text1</p> <br />Text2 <br /> <p> </p> <br/>
<p>Text11</p> <br />Text12 <br /> <p> </p> <br/>
'''
while True: # Use cycle to process one by one
    o = regSearch(html,"<br\s*/>[^<]*<br\s*/>") # Take out the data to be replaced
    if not o: break
    n = replaceReg(o,"<br\s*/>","<p>",1) # Replace start
    n = replaceReg(n,"<br\s*/>","</p>",1) # Replace end
    html = html.replace(o,n)
print (html)
```

Result:

```
<p>Text1</p> <p>Text2 </p> <p> </p> <br/>
<p>Text11</p> <p>Text12 </p> <p> </p> <br/>
```